# Get the variables of a loop from an include file

Tags: craft3, loop, include, plugin-supertable

So my 1. file is "_overview-topicTeaser.twig" which is within a matrix:

```
{% include 'modules/module-squareteaser/_module-squareteaser' with {
  squareTeasers: block.topicTeaserItems.all(),
  squareteaserHeadline: block.topicTeaserItems.one().entryTopicHeadline
} %}
```

And my 2. file is "_module-squareteaser.twig":

> ```
>     <div class="squareteaser__wrapper _parent-3-child">
>       {% for item in squareTeasers %}
>
>         {% include 'modules/module-squareteaser/_module-squareteaser-item' with {
>           headline: squareteaserHeadline
>         } %}
>
>       {% endfor %}
>     </div>
> ```

So i am looping in the 2. file the file "_module-squareteaser-item.twg" and want to put out the "squareteaserHeadline" in the frontend. But it always gives me the same headline from my first teaser in the loop, makes sense to me cause i am using the "one()" when i include the variable "squareteaserHeadline" in the first file.  But if i delete the "one()" i get nothing... so how do i get all teasers whith their own headline?

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Can't you fetch all the blocks with `block.topicTeaserItems.all()`

```
{% include 'modules/module-squareteaser/_module-squareteaser' with {
  squareTeasers: block.topicTeaserItems.all()
} %}
```

And then you display the headlines with `item.entryTopicHeadline`

```
<div class="squareteaser__wrapper _parent-3-child">
  {% for item in squareTeasers %}
    {% include 'modules/module-squareteaser/_module-squareteaser-item' with {
      headline: item.entryTopicHeadline
    } %}
  {% endfor %}
</div>
```

A simplified version would look like

```
<div class="squareteaser__wrapper _parent-3-child">
    {% for item in block.topicTeaserItems.all() %}
        {{ item.entryTopicHeadline }}
    {% endfor %}
</div>
```

Comment: Sure i could do it with "item.entryTopicHeadline". But i am using the "_module-squareteaser.twig" for multiple includes at different places on the website. So thats why i wanna go with just "squareteaserHeadline", Thought its somehow possible.

Comment: You would have to create a new array of headlines by looping through all blocks in your `_overview-topicTeaser.twig`

Comment: And how i do this? :)

Comment: This would be a new question, but there are plenty examples how to create an array in twig. https://twig.symfony.com/doc/2.x/filters/merge.html